# Using oledbdatatreader inside the oledbdatareader

Tags: c#

I have code like

```
DatabaseConnection.MyExecuteNonQuery(comd);
cmd.CommandText = "select heads,formulla,fields from tbl_empsalstructear where empcode='" + emp.empid + "' order by headid";
OleDbDataReader rdr = DatabaseConnection.MyExecuteReader(cmd);
while (rdr.Read())
{
```

Here I have another function which returns a string value

```
string abc=function();
```

and then I use

```
string jkl=rdr[0].tostring()
```

which returns no value
and says no data in  row n column but when I remove that function inside while it works properly and in that function I have another data reader that is closed 
                 }

Comment: I think you're mixing reader access methods (iterating and direct indexing) Check the Msdn examples on how to read values from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [checking for NULL values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before trying to access the data.

The link above states;

`Call this method to look for null column values before calling the typed get methods (for example, GetByte, GetChar, and so on) to avoid raising an error.`

I typically use SqlDataReader, but an example of what I do is as follows. Note the rdr.IsDBNull call. Do that for any column that allows nulls;

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnstring"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = SQL_COURSE_COMPONENTS; // Constant to my SQL statement containing a parameter @CourseId
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@CourseId";
            param.Value = CourseId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int CODE_ORDINAL = rdr.GetOrdinal("Code");

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string code = rdr.IsDBNull(CODE_ORDINAL) ? (string)null : rdr.GetString(CODE_ORDINAL);
                    // .... Rest of the code here
                }
            }
        }
```